# No installed software button in App Center in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10, app-center

I just installed a new, fresh Ubuntu 23.10. I want to delete all games, but I can't find list of installed software, so that I can delete unnecessary programs.

There is no installed software button in the App Center.

[image: no installed software button in App Center]

Manage items:

[image: Manage item]

Comment: This is just a comment... I never use the "software" GUI in Ubuntu to install, update, or remove any software; it is just a mess, very misleading, and a buggy piece of app. You should instead use `apt` and `snap` from command line.

Comment: Tick "Show system apps", and upload a picture.
If you still don't see them, try installing gnome-software, and delete them from it instead.

Comment: @FedKad notice this is tagged [tag:app-centre] - this is a rewrite to solve exactly those problems - something very important if we want Ubuntu to start being used by less technically savvy users!

Answer (score 0):

You can install and update your software and show a list of installed software in the Ubuntu Software app. To install Ubuntu Software in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```